# Dynamic Web Project not reading css

Tags: java, css, eclipse, jsp

I am trying to load css for a jsp in my project. The path to where the CSS is located is ProjectName > WebContent > resources > css > xxx.css

in my jsp page I used this to try and load the css

```
<c:url value="resources/css/xxx.css" var="cssvar" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${cssvar }" type="text/css" />
```

and different varients as well..(without using the c:url too) but it seems no matter what I try the css doesn't load and in my chrome console it's giving me this error.

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) followed by the path that I provide.

Anyone have a clue as to why this is happening to me?

Comment: Did you try "<c:url value="/resources/css/xxx.css" var="cssvar" />"
use a  "/" before  resources ?

Comment: @Moolerian sure did.

Comment: Is this when launching from Eclipse or after it's exported as a war? What's responsible for the project's deployment? Eclipse? Maven? Something else?

Comment: I am launching it in Eclipse. This project is being deployed as a Spring project, and it does have Maven.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i solve it by importing css in this way :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/public/ui/css/rtl/index.css">
```

the index.css located in

> projectName/src/main/webapp/public/ui/css/rtl/index.css

Comment: For Dynamic Web Projects, isn't your CSS supposed to be under WebContent?

Comment: No dice, my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

Write this in your jsp file from where you want to add css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/xxx.css">
```

make sure you href is correct i.e. if your jsp is in WebContent then this href is correct

Comment: did you confirm by seeing inspect element ?

Comment: Yes, it's the same thing.